# "FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted." in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, linux-mint

I have downloaded a Linux Mint ISO file from online and I've configured VirtualBox to boot from that ISO.

[image]
[image]

It can start the guest OS correctly the first time. But when I try to restart the guest OS from within, I always get the error: `FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted.` 
[image]

Why is this happening? Why can't VirtualBox remember the settings used to boot when the guest OS restarts? How can I make the guest OS always boot using the ISO image specified in the VM's settings?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a bug in VirtualBox.  I just tried what you're doing on my system and it looks like after it boots from the Optical, it will not boot from that drive again until the VM is completely halted, even if the optical drive is the only storage the VM has.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but from the looks of it, you could always install the OS onto another hard drive.  After you do that, install the guest additions and shut down the VM completely.  Next, make the hard drive Immutable in the media manager.  Each time you shutdown and power up the VM, all changes to the hard drive image will be discarded and it will be like new each time.

Edit:  I just launched the VM with a Mint ISO, and vdi.  After the live OS booted, I did a `dd` to copy everything from the ISO to the vdi and rebooted.  Everything seems to be like it's a Live CD, and it reboots without an issue.  Still might want to make the hard drive Immutable though, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for corruption of your iso file.
An easy way to do so is comparsion of hashsums.

I found [this](https://linuxmint.com/verify.php) on the Linux Mint Homepage:

> **Steps to verify an ISO image**
>
> The following steps should be performed to verify an ISO image:
>
> Import the signing key from a Keyserver (see above).   Verify its
>   fingerprint with the following command:
>
> ```
> gpg --list-keys --with-fingerprint
> ```
>
> Download the ISO image, the sha256sum.txt and the sha256sum.txt.gpg
>   into the same directory.   Verify the signature on the sha256sum files
>   with the following command (the output of this command should mention
>   that the signature is "Good"):
>
> ```
> gpg --verify sha256sum.txt.gpg sha256sum.txt
> ```
>
> Once this is done, the sha256sum.txt can be trusted.   Generate the
>   sha256 sum of your ISO image, and compare it to the sum present in the
>   sha256sums.txt file.
>
> ```
> sha256sum -b yourisoimagefile.iso
> ```
>
> If the signature was "Good" and the sha256 sums match, you
>   successfully verified the integrity and authenticity of the ISO image.

Comment: Also, are you sure the Mint iso is assigned to be booted, not the Guest Additions?

Comment: if image is corrupted how come first boot worked?

Comment: Uhh, I overread that part. Seems to be a problem with the bootloader config of the guest.

Answer (score -2):

You should not use the Live-CD check box if it is an iso.

Live-CD means that what you are reading is a real CD in a real drive, not an iso.
I am not sure if that is the issue, but it's worth a try.

Comment: No, _Host Drive_ option is reading from physical CD drive, _Live CD_ refers to a preinstalled portable OS on the CD.